# Break one string to multiple variables using R or SQLite

Tags: r, sqlite, dplyr

I have a dataset which has four string variables corresponding to the answers of a candidate to a test, like this: "*ECEABBBDACBBBADEEDCBBCBCEBAACABEABECCEADEADCE*".

The dataset has four tests (four variables) with 45 answers (45 is the length of the string) and I wish to break each variable into 45, totalizing 180 variables.

I have:

```
NU_INSCRICAO* | TX_RESPOSTAS_CN | TX_RESPOSTAS_CH | TX_RESPOSTAS_LC | TX_RESPOSTAS_MT
```

I expect:

```
NU_INSCRICAO* | Q1 | Q2 | ... | Q179 | Q180
```

* *NU_INSCRICAO is my ID column*

Link to the sample dataset: https://pastebin.com/YK477UzW

My code:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(sample)) {
    for(j in 2:5) {
        for(k in 1:45) {
            answer <- substring(sample[i, j], k, k)
            correct <- substring(sample[i, j], k, k)

            if(answer == correct) {
                output*[i, (((j - 1) * k) + 1)] <- 1
            } else {
                output*[i, (((j - 1) * k) + 1)] <- 0
            }
        }
    }
}
```

* *The structure of output data frame was previously created with NU_INSCRICAO copied from the sample dataset*

I want to know a better way to do this.

The sample dataset has 1000 rows, but my real dataset has more than 3 million, so any suggestions about doing this with SQLite will help me as well.

* *All the * in this post is only for illustrative purpose of this post, they aren't in the real code*

Answer (score 0):

Read text file into R dataframe `dt`:

```
dt <- read.table("sample.txt", sep = ";", header = T, stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Combine columns `NU_INSCRICAO` to `TX_RESPOSTAS_MT`, split it by character, and spread into columns. Set column name

```
out <- data.frame(dt$NU_INSCRICAO, (do.call(rbind, strsplit(paste0(dt$TX_RESPOSTAS_CN, dt$TX_RESPOSTAS_CH, dt$TX_RESPOSTAS_LC, dt$TX_RESPOSTAS_MT),""))))
names(out) <- c("NU_INSCRICAO", paste0("Q", 1:185))
```

[image: output]

Comment: Thanks, you solution really helped me, but I wonder if there is a way to optimize this code. I have 16 GB and it isn't enough, even in this case. Like I said, I have a 3M x 20 data frame.

Answer (score 0):

It seems from the data that you are interested only in first 5 columns of the text file. We can read the data in R and use `cSplit` from `splitstackshape` to get data from multiple columns in separate columns.

```
dt <- read.table("sample.txt", sep = ";", header = TRUE)[1:5]
new_dt <- splitstackshape::cSplit(dt, names(dt)[-1], sep = "", stripWhite = FALSE)
```